# XOR Clauses for Z3 SAT Solver

Tags: z3, xor, conjunctive-normal-form

I am using Z3 to solve satisfiability problems including several hundred XOR clauses with 22 inputs each. To code the XOR clauses in DIMACS form, I am using Tseitin encoding. My conversion breaks the XORs down to smaller CNF clauses with up to five literals each. Z3 so far is not able to devise a SAT solution.

What could/should I do to improve my encoding?

I have looked at Gaussian elimination, but this probably does not help, because the XOR expressions do not have the same input variables.

Answer (score 2):

Z3 has two SAT solver engines, you can enable the more efficient engine using the
strategy framework. For example, see the tutorial [Z3 - strategies](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/strategies)

There is a section the illustrates the use of strategies for bit-vector formulas:

```
 (declare-const x (_ BitVec 16))
 (declare-const y (_ BitVec 16))
 (assert (= (bvor x y) (_ bv13 16)))
 (assert (bvslt x y))
 (check-sat-using (then simplify solve-eqs bit-blast sat))
 (get-model)
```

That said, it is relatively easy to generate hard 
instances for CDCL based SAT solvers using XOR.
For example:

```
Randal E. Bryant: A View from the Engine Room: Computational Support for Symbolic Model Checking. 25 Years of Model Checking 2008: 145-149
```

Z3's more efficient sat solver (called by the example above) have some 
data-structures for detecting and propagating with xors (equivalences).

Comment: Using the SMT2 input format and bit vectors is usually/potentially more efficient than using DIMACS/CNF as Z3 input?

Comment: quick notes: 1- the efficient SAT solver is used by default for problems containing only bit-vectors, so there is no need to use `check-sat-using`.  2- Z3 does not have support for xor clauses like CryptoMinisat. Encoding the problem in SMT2 input format will not help. The support for Xor clauses is not difficult to implement. However, it is not in our TODO list. If you are interested, I can show what needs to be done to implement the Crytominisat approach into Z3.