# Z3 solver.check() taking a long time in python3

Tags: python, z3py

I am running a z3 solver in order to reverse engineer some seeds, and I have found the solver.check() function taking quite a long time in certain situations. Here is the function in question:

```
def sym_xoroshiro128plus(sym_s0, sym_s1, result):

    sym_r = (sym_s0 + sym_s1) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  
    condition = (sym_r & 0xFFFFFFFF) == result

    sym_s0, sym_s1 = sym_xoroshiro128plusadvance(sym_s0, sym_s1)

    return sym_s0, sym_s1, condition

def sym_xoroshiro128plus64bit(sym_s0, sym_s1, result):

    condition = ((sym_s0 + sym_s1) & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) == result

    sym_s0, sym_s1 = sym_xoroshiro128plusadvance(sym_s0, sym_s1)

    return sym_s0, sym_s1, condition

def sym_xoroshiro128plusadvance(sym_s0, sym_s1):
    s0 = sym_s0
    s1 = sym_s1
    
    s1 ^= s0
    sym_s0 = z3.RotateLeft(s0, 24) ^ s1 ^ (s1 << 16)
    sym_s1 = z3.RotateLeft(s1, 37)

    return sym_s0, sym_s1

def get_models(s):

    result = []
    i = 0
    while s.check() == z3.sat:
        print(f"Model check {i}")
        print(f"S check {s.check()}")
        i += 1
        m = s.model()
        result.append(m)
        
        # Constraint that makes current answer invalid
        d = m[0]
        c = d()
        s.add(c != m[d])

    return result


def find_seeds_arceus(ec,pid,rolls):

    solver = z3.Solver()
    start_s0 = z3.BitVecs('start_s0', 64)[0]

    sym_s0 = start_s0
    sym_s1 = 0x82A2B175229D6A5B

    # EC call
    result = ec
    sym_s0, sym_s1, condition = sym_xoroshiro128plus(sym_s0, sym_s1, result)
    solver.add(condition)

    # SIDTID call
    sym_s0, sym_s1 = sym_xoroshiro128plusadvance(sym_s0, sym_s1)

    # Initial PID rolls
    for i in range(rolls-1):
        sym_s0, sym_s1, condition = sym_xoroshiro128plus(sym_s0, sym_s1, result)

    # PID call
    result = pid
    sym_s0, sym_s1, condition = sym_xoroshiro128plus(sym_s0, sym_s1, result)
    solver.add(condition)

    models = get_models(solver)
    return [model[start_s0].as_long() for model in models]
```

as long as the rolls value is 1 or 2, it completes fairly quickly. However, when the rolls value is above 4, the program halts at s.check() and I do not know what it is doing. I'm not entirely sure why it's taking so long to check the solver. Is there a faster, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: These sorts of "xor" based problems are typically pretty difficult for SAT solvers to handle. They end up forcing the solver to do a brute-force for most of the time. Why do you expect this to go faster?

Comment: I wasn't sure, but I was hoping that there was a way to either make it more efficient or change the strategy. Is there a solver that is better at this kind of work?

Comment: These problems are inherently difficult for solvers. See, for instance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420486/xor-clauses-for-z3-sat-solver and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599423/optimize-solver-tactics-for-circuit-sat for similar questions in the past.